Please help me identify this model?
Came with a squad of khorne bezerkers, but I'm trialling my new death guard colourings on him. Is he a champion? A sergent? A lord? What sward is that, an astartes chainsward? A single lightening claw 


That appears to be a modified Bezerker model;
The chainsword is available in the standard sprue for a Khrone World Eaters Squad, but for the left hand, and the wrist guard is from a different sword.
As for the lightning claw, 10th edition does not allow Bezerkers to take these as weapons, but some previous editions (including 9th) allowed for "corrupted weapons", so this is most likely taken from a regular Astartes captain.
You could play this model as a proxy, or in games of 9th edition.


I wouldn't refer to a non-strictly-wysiwyg model as a proxy. It's still a khorne bezerker
